# Highlight specific dot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using ggplot2 in R. I have data as follows in csv format

```
         A                B

-4.051587034    -2.388276692

-4.389339837    -3.742321425

-4.047207557    -3.460923901

-4.458420756    -2.462180905

-2.12090412     -2.251811973
```

I want to high light specific two dot with corresponds -2.462180905 and -3.742321425 and to in plot with different colors. Which should to different than default colors in the plot. I tried following code

```
library(ggplot2)

library(reshape2)

library(methods)

library(RSvgDevice)

Data<-read.csv("table.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

data1<-Data[,-3]

plot2<-ggplot(data1,aes(x = A, y = B)) + geom_point(aes(size=2,color=ifelse(y=-2.462180905,'red')))

graph<-plot2 + theme_bw()+opts(axis.line = theme_segment(colour = "black"),panel.grid.major=theme_blank(),panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(),panel.border = theme_blank())

ggsave(graph,file="figure.svg",height=6,width=7)
```

It is not working the way i want. It gives all dots in same color. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, which may be more or less efficient depending on your requirements, would be to add another geom_point():

```
x <- c(-4.051587034, -4.389339837, -4.047207557, -4.458420756, -2.12090412)
y <- c(-2.388276692, -3.742321425, -3.460923901, -2.462180905, -2.251811973)
d <- data.frame(x, y)

require("ggplot2")
h <- c(2, 4)  # put row numbers in here or use condition

ggplot() +
   geom_point(data = d, aes(x, y), colour = "red", size = 5) +
   geom_point(data = d[h, ], aes(x, y), colour = "blue", size = 5)
# notice the colour is outside the aesthetic arguments
```

Which gives you this:

[image: highlighted points]

Comment: I found your answer very useful as I am trying to have two datasets on one plot. Don't need to merge and create dummy variables now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a different column with the same value for all points except the highlighted point,  assign the colour aesthetic to that column, then change the colours manually.

```
data1$highlight <- data1$B == -2.462180905  # FALSE except for the one you want

ggplot(data1, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = highlight), size = 2) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "black", "TRUE" = "red"))
```

Note that the condition in the first line will have to be exact in order to get `TRUE` at the right row. Either ensure the value is exact or use a condition that will match the desired row.

Also note that `opts` is deprecated. Use `theme` instead. But that's another question.